add group by on a column if just a condition exists
in Rdlc report in report viewer ,I want to add group by on a column if just a condition ...... exists
 =iif(Variables!SNEWPAGE.Value="1",Fields!BOX_Comp.Value,......

but I don't do what should I add if Variables!SNEWPAGE.Value is not "1"
I want to add it to group on of group properties of Tablix


Show some sample data from your dataset and your expected results. You can't switch grouping on or off directly but you can mimic this behaviour in some circumstances. Edit your question to show more info .

How do you want the Group to work when Snew Page <> 1? I usually use 1 as the ELSE - It'll group all the records together if snew page <> 1. If you want all the individual records, you'll need to use a unique record ID as the Else.
